# How do I get the most gifts?

Tags: icy-gifts-2

In the game [Icy Gifts 2](http://www.kongregate.com/games/SilenGames/icy-gifts-2), there is a slot machine that you can use to gamble coins away in the hopes of earning powerups and gifts. Alternatively, coins can be traded for five gifts without any gambling involved.

Assuming that:

- I have the "Luck" upgrade (which gives an increased chance of winning the slot machine) fully maxed
- I don't care about the other powerups, only gifts

Which method has the highest ROI per coin? Samples of adequately large sizes will probably have to do, unless the algorithm has actually been posted somewhere.

Comment: Fair warning - the game is extremely addictive. Don't click the link if you have anything to do for the next few hours

Comment: Damn you for showing me this game.  I just lost an hour and a half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the slot machine odds, but by far the fastest way to get gifts is to replay certain levels.  For example, on level 18, I can click the bomb pretty much anywhere and guarantee 80 gifts.  If you replay a level, you get to keep the gifts from each replay.

**Update:**

I finished the game, and had 389 coins to spare.  If I had cashed in the coins for gifts, I would have received 1945 gifts (389 coins * 5 gifts / coin).

Instead of cashing them in, I played slots.  I started with 3 gifts, and at the very end of slots I ended up with 3713 gifts.

That means I earned **191% more gifts by playing slots** than by exchanging the coins for gifts.  This is with luck maxed out.

Now, this is with a sample size of 1, but I feel like the high ratio pretty much guarantees that playing slots will pay out higher for you.

**Update 2:**

I played again until I reached 80 coins, and my slots-to-exchange ratio was a little lower at **164%**.
...And I just tried again, also with 80 coins, and the ratio was **180%**.

Do with this information what you will, but I think it's conclusive that the slots give you more gifts for your coins.

Comment: And in level 22, you're pretty much guaranteed 108.

Comment: Level 45 you get 210 gifts in no time at all.